# Category Weighting with Total Marks Override

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a teacher gradebook that uses category weighting (and evaluation weighting within each category). The formula I use to calculate final grade is found in column E here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TMsuJWtc4C7tebZGVVyeA4qbmLCnGZRi55ZRJsI-jGE/edit?usp=sharing

What I would like to do is give teachers an option to reduce the total marks for any particular student for an evaluation.

Example:

- Evaluation total marks is 10, student mark is 4 (40%)
- Teacher decides to make the total marks for this student = 5.
- Teacher would enter: **4 [5]** where **4 is the student mark** and **[5] is the new total marks** for the evaluation.  New percentage is 80%

I have written the formula to calculate the new percentage without issue however I cannot figure out how to get the final grade for this student.

In the linked spreadsheet above, student 1 and student 2 should have the same final grade in column E.

How can I change my formula in column E (starting at E8) to include cases like 4 [5]?

Comment: There's something odd about this - I can see why 4/10 would be 40%, but not why changing the marks to 5 would make it 80%?

Comment: Because 4 out of 5 is 80%

Comment: OK, got it, thanks.

Comment: @TomSharpe my fault, I see how I was unclear, I edited the question to clarify that the new evaluation total marks is 5.

Comment: No, I was a bit slow there, I should have been able to work it out. I don't know if anyone will come up with a full answer to this, but the short answer seem to be that you would have to change the total mark in N3 as well as the percentage, unless you can use the percentages to calculate the result rather than the raw marks?

Comment: @TomSharpe you're right, using the percentages is the way to go, I did that with my non-category based gradebook, not sure why I didn't do that here. I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was fun!  Using the recommendation of @TomSharpe I came up with this that seems to work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($C8),"",IFERROR((

Settings!$E$3*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$3)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$3,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$3,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$4*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$4)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$4,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$4,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$5*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$5)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$5,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$5,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$6*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$6)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$6,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$6,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$7*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$7)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$7,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$7,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$8*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$8)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$8,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$8,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$9*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$9)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$9,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$9,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$10*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$10)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$10,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$10,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$11*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$11)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$11,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$11,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

+
Settings!$E$12*(IF(COUNTIF($N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$12)=0,0,SUMPRODUCT($O8:$HE8,$N$5:$HD$5=Settings!$D$12,$N$4:$HD$4)*100/SUMIFS($N$4:$HD$4,$N$5:$HD$5,Settings!$D$12,$O8:$HE8,">=0",$N$3:$HD$3,">=0")))

)/(IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$3,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$3,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$4,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$4,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$5,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$5,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$6,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$6,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$7,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$7,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$8,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$8,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$9,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$9,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$10,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$10,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$11,N8:HE8,"<>")>=1,Settings!$E$11,0)+IF(COUNTIFS($N$5:$HE$5,Settings!$D$12,N8:HE8,"<>"
)>=1,Settings!$E$12,0)),"No Grade"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution would be to rewrite your formula in column E to use the numbers from the percentage column to calculate the grade, instead of using the complicated string you will find in the marks column.

Example formula that you could use in E8:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(N8:Y8,ISFORMULA(N8:Y8))*FILTER(N$4:Y$4,ISNUMBER(N$4:Y$4))) *100 / SUM(N$4:Y$4),"")
```

Comment: you're right, using percentages would be better.  Also your formula does not take into account categories.